# MySql field size for storing email body

Tags: mysql, size, field

I want to store contents of email body into MySql.
What would the correct type&size of the field be?
Can varchar() provide enough storage size?
Is there a limitation in the email body's length?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use blob or text types. There is no limit on the length of an email body.

Comment: thanks for replying :)
Do u know if there is any limitation on the size/length of the mail's body?

Comment: There is no intrinsic limit that I know of. Though every email server will have their own limit. 10MB is pretty standard from my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

"A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

Comment: BLOB is slower than TEXT, because it's stored in a separate file.