# What size do I need to safely store HD serials?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

- **I want to store HD serials into MySQL/MariaDB. What would the correct
  type&size of the field be?**

To avoid the major confusion generated in the comments I've edited my question to reflect only the relevant part of what I am questioning here. Which is in a way similar to this other question which, from what I can see is not off-topic and fairly accepted [MySql field size for storing email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766449/mysql-field-size-for-storing-email-body) I could list many other examples of similar questions if needed, so I don't know what all the hate is...

Comment: ***which was soon overruled on my tests*** Interesting. I have yet to see a drive with a serial longer than 30 characters and I have a couple hundred drives at work. Although I usually get the serials on linux since the bulk of my drives at work are on linux servers.

Comment: @drescherjm the highest one I've got so far was 40 characters, but it starts with a bunch of 2020202020 which perhaps are placeholders that are not in use at the moment and I should just discard those? `2020202020202020162115334430362161324217`

Comment: @Guapo Post a [MCVE], otherwise your question is _off-topic_.

Comment: Maybe it's some type of failure in reading the correct value.

Comment: Do you have this drive? Can't you look at the physical label on the drive? ***2020202020202020162115334430362161324217*** That looks very unusual for a drive serial number. I have never seen a drive serial like that and I have drives from all current manufacturers.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, I do but can't remove it as its in use full time... I've also tested it with a different code found on codeproject and it gave me out the exact same value.

Comment: Did you try a different program like CrystalDiskInfo?

Comment: @Guapo Well, no I'm not giving _unreasonable comments_. It's your turn to improve your question seriously! Be sure I'm understanding what you're asking about, but you simply rendered your question _off-topic_ at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @drescherjm here is another application I get the same results with https://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/gethardwareinformation.aspx as for CrystalDiskInfo, it does indeed spit out a different serial...

Comment: I think for some reason the result you get back is wrong. I have no idea why the code is producing the wrong result however.

Comment: As for the code I agree with @πάνταῥεῖ on that. You should post the code here in your question instead of it being linked to a different site.

Comment: @Guapo You should take into account the criticism above. It is unclear what you are asking and it certainly has nothing to do with c++.

Comment: @RawN I am sorry but my question is not directly at the code but clearly stated, so that would also make this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766449/mysql-field-size-for-storing-email-body question off-topic as an example... so if I strip everything off of the question and only leave: `I want to store serial HD content to MySQL. What would be the type&size of the field be?` it would have avoided all this?

Comment: This may be a better question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: ***it certainly has nothing to do with c++*** It think the code produces the wrong result so it may be a code bug causing this. Or even possibly a windows bug. This is why I asked @Guapo to check a different program or look at the drive label.

Comment: `20202020...` also seems suspiciously reminiscent of `%20%20%20%20...`

Comment: @drescherjm `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` so perhaps what crystal give us could be the volume info represented as hex instead? And on another machine I get the same result for 2 HD's (the 2020202 at the start) while the other 2 show differently, WD-WCASYC000000(I've edited the extra digits to 0 but they are 6) and 123659020000280800BD

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot funny enough `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` also gives me that, running from the command line... see previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `VARCHAR(50)` and move on to some other issue.

Even if serial numbers are never longer than, say, 30 characters, saying 50 has no impact on disk space, and virtually no impact on performance.

(20 is hex for a space.  All the characters in the first example could be *octal* digits.)

Details

`VARCHAR` takes 1 or 2 bytes for length, plus the necessary number of bytes for the string.  30 digits stored in `VARCHAR(30)` takes no less disk space than in `VARCHAR(50)`.

In certain complex queries, `VARCHAR` *may* be turned into `CHAR`, thereby occupying the max length *for the duration of the tmp table for the query*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind elaborating a bit more on this `saying 50 has no impact on disk space, and virtually no impact on performance.` or is that just some arbitrary numbers as an example?